# group_by function in 'dplyr' package only return one value

Tags: r

I have tried several times, but the function `group_by` returns only one value, and the function 'ddply' in the `plyr` package returns several values that are more suited to what I intended.

Check my simple code

```
library(MASS)
library(dplyr)
library(plyr)

Cars93$cnt <- rep(1,norw(Cars93))

#using group_by function 
Cars93 %>% group_by(Type) %>% summarise( n = sum(cnt))

#group_by returns 
#  n
#1 6

#using ddply function 
ddply (Cars93,.(Type), summarise, n = sum(cnt) )

#ddply returns

#     Type  n
#1 Compact 16
#2   Large 11
#3 Midsize 22
#4   Small 21
#5  Sporty 14
#6     Van  9
```

I want the group_by function to return exactly the same result as the `ddply` function.

Comment: It is because you have loaded both `dplyr` and `plyr` which is masking `summarise` function. Do `Cars93 %>% group_by(Type) %>% dplyr::summarise( n = sum(cnt))`

Comment: thank you! , you save me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another method you can use is the function `tally` which counts by each group, saving the need for creating a new column.

```
Cars93 %>% 
  group_by(Type) %>% 
  tally()

# A tibble: 6 x 2
  Type        n
  <fct>   <int>
1 Compact    16
2 Large      11
3 Midsize    22
4 Small      21
5 Sporty     14
6 Van         9
```